# Selenium: Unable to locate element by class and id

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape a website, I created a loop and was able to locate all the elements. My problem is, that the *next button* id changes on every page. So I can not use the `id` as a `locator`.

This is the *next button* on page 1:

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="f_c7" href="#" class="nextLink jasty-link"></a>
```

And this is the next button on page 2:

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="f_c9" href="#" class="nextLink jasty-link"></a>
```

---

Idea:

```
next_button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("nextLink jasty-link")
next_button.click
```

I get this error message:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

The problem here might be that there are two next buttons on the page.
So I tried to create a list but the list is empty.

```
next_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("nextLink jasty-link")
print(next_buttons)
```

Any idea on how to solve my problem? Would really appreciate it.

This is the website:

https://fazarchiv.faz.net/faz-portal/faz-archiv?q=Kryptow%C3%A4hrungen&source=&max=10&sort=&offset=0&_ts=1657629187558#hitlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in my opinion:

- Depending from where you try to access the site there is a cookie banner that will get the click, so you may have to accept it first:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_class_name('cb-enable').click()
  ```
- To locate a single element, one of the both next buttons, it doeas not matter, use `browser.find_element()` instead of `browser.find_elements()`.

  Selecting your element by multiple class names use `xpath`:

  ```
  next_button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class, "nextLink jasty-link")]')
  ```

  or `css selectors`:

  ```
  next_button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.nextLink.jasty-link')
  ```

**Note:** *To avoid `DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element()` import in addition [`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)*

Answer (score 0):

You can't get elements by multiple class names. So, you can use `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead.

```py
next_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".nextLink.jasty-link")
print(next_buttons)
```

You can then loop through the list and click the buttons:

```py
next_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".nextLink.jasty-link")
for button in next_buttons:
  button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xPath

```
//a[contains(@class, 'step jasty-link')]/following-sibling::a
```